# Left Outer Join Subquery

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to do a left outer join to a subquery, is that possible?

Can I do something like this?:

```
##this is this weeks targets
select * from targets t
inner join streams s on s.id = t.stream_id
where t.week_no =WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())

left outer join

(
###############This is records selected so far this week
select p.brand_id, p.part_product_family, sum(r.best) from records r 
inner join products p on p.id = r.product_id
left outer join streams s on s.body = p.brand_id and s.stream = p.part_product_family
where WEEKOFYEAR(r.date_selected) =WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
group by p.brand_id, p.part_product_family;
) sq_2

on s.stream = sq_2.part_product_family
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
    ##this is this weeks targets
select * from targets t
inner join streams s on s.id = t.stream_id

left outer join

(
###############This is records selected so far this week
select p.brand_id, p.part_product_family, sum(r.best) from records r 
inner join products p on p.id = r.product_id
left outer join streams s on s.body = p.brand_id and s.stream = p.part_product_family
where WEEKOFYEAR(r.date_selected) =WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) and YEAR(r.date_selected) = YEAR(now())
group by p.brand_id, p.part_product_family
) sq_2

on s.body = sq_2.brand_id and s.stream = sq_2.part_product_family
```